# Play mutiple audio at a time

Tags: android, audio-processing

I need to play multiple audio track at a time from sd card. I was trying to play with SoundPool. But it does not support larger files.

I tried with AudioTrack but it needs pure PCM code. PCM code generation bit of complex from mp3 or 3gp file, as android do not have anything build in to that.

I've look OpenSL Engine, But did not find any good example or tutorial to work with it.

How can I play multiple audio at a time in loopy style? any idea, suggestion would be great a help.

Comment: how big are your sound files? What problem specifically do you run into when trying SoundPool?

Comment: About 3-5mb. SoundPool doesn't play full sound.